# smach_viewer throws KeyError

Tags: python-3.x, ros, state-machine

I'm trying to implement a simple state machine on ROS using SMACH and visualize it using smach_viewer.
The system I'm using:

- Ubuntu 18.04
- ROS Melodic (catkin_ws is configured to use Python3!)

My smach-implementation looks like this (test.py):

```
  #!/usr/bin/env python3

  import smach
  import smach_ros
  import rospy

  class t1(smach.State):
    def __init__(self, outcomes=['successful', 'failed']):
        smach.State.__init__(self, outcomes)

    def execute(self, userdata):
        return 'successful'

  class t2(smach.State):
    def __init__(self, outcomes=['successful']):
        smach.State.__init__(self, outcomes)

    def execute(self, userdata):
        #time.sleep(2)
        return 'successful'

  class t3(smach.State):
    def __init__(self, outcomes=['successful']):
        smach.State.__init__(self, outcomes)

    def execute(self, userdata):
        #time.sleep(2)
        return 'successful'


  if __name__=="__main__":
    rospy.init_node('test_state_machine')

    sm_top = smach.StateMachine(outcomes=['success'])
    with sm_top:
        smach.StateMachine.add('T1', t1(),
                                   transitions={'successful': 'T2', 'failed': 'T3'})
        smach.StateMachine.add('T2', t2(),
                                   transitions={'successful': 'T1'})
        smach.StateMachine.add('T3', t3(),
                                   transitions={'successful': 'success'})

    # Create and start the introspection server
    sis = smach_ros.IntrospectionServer('introspection_server', sm_top, '/SM_ROOT')
    sis.start()
    # Execute SMACH plan
    outcome = sm_top.execute()
    # Wait for ctrl-c to stop the application
    rospy.spin()
    sis.stop()
```

According to the output in my terminal the state machine runs perfectly fine. But when I try to visualize the SM using smach_viewer, the smach_viewer throws the following error:

```
[ERROR] [1599821587.164191]: bad callback: <bound method SmachViewerFrame._status_msg_update of <__main__.SmachViewerFrame; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'wxFrame *' at 0x55616f7eb050> >>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/topics.py", line 750, in _invoke_callback
    cb(msg)
  File "/home/faps/catkin_ws/src/executive_smach_visualization/smach_viewer/scripts/smach_viewer.py", line 844, in _status_msg_update
    if container.update_status(msg):
  File "/home/faps/catkin_ws/src/executive_smach_visualization/smach_viewer/scripts/smach_viewer.py", line 185, in update_status
    self._local_data._data = pickle.loads(msg.local_data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1388, in loads
    return Unpickler(file).load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 864, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1157, in load_get
    self.append(self.memo[self.readline()[:-1]])
KeyError: 'AJ9cQA'
```

Any ideas on what could be the issue and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made sure to have the right branch activated (in my case the melodic-devel branch) and ran

```
rosdep install smach_viewer
```

(which I forgot earlier).

Doing so, smach_viewer at least shows the state machine correctly. Nevertheless, in the terminal the error keeps showing up.

Since at least the visualization works now, I'll mark this as the answer. For more information check out the issue thread [here](https://github.com/ros-visualization/executive_smach_visualization/issues/33).